# Sending intents using ADB with additional action, data, and extra

Tags: adb, shell, intents

How do I convert the following Java code to an ADB command?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("com.glass.videoglass://"));
intent.putExtra("startFromWS", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

The only thing I've seen so far is

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Android developer documentation [explains how to specify an intent in the argument to the `am` command](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#IntentSpec).

In your case you want `-a` to specify the action, `-d` to specify the data URI, and `--ez` to specify a Boolean extra. You can find the action name by looking up [`Intent.ACTION_VIEW`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) in the documentation. Putting all of that together, you get:-

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d com.glass.videoglass:// --ez startFromWS true
```