# Pass extra data into `am start` command

Tags: 7.0-nougat, gps, shell, geolocation

Nougat Android (7.1.2)

What I use actually (it works), the app starts with the last know location:

```
am start com.location.provider
```

What I'm looking for like:

```
am start com.location.provider -e longitude 28 -e latitude 77
```

or

```
am start com.location.provider -d gps://13,678173-2,033719
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Related/possibly duplicate: [Sending intents using ADB with additional action, data, and extra](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/68105/44325). The answer links to [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#IntentSpec)

Comment: On all devices I have checked `am start com.location.provider` just produces an error that there is no Intent to start (most likely because there is no com.location.provider package.

Comment: com.location.provider works on bluestacks 4 emulator -> https://www.bluestacks.com/fr/index.html