# How to open a specific page in OneNote app on Android via adb?

Tags: adb, intents, microsoft-onenote

I'd like to make use of an Android tablet to write on OneNote pages that I'm actively viewing in a Windows computer. From the Windows computer, I get two links when I right click on a page and select "Copy link to page". These links look like the following:

```
https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=...
onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/...
```

The second link that starts with `onenote:https://d...` is useful when I want to jump to the page on another Windows computer - I can feed it to the Run window, and the OneNote app will display the page I need it to go to.

---

**Question**: with **adb**, can I achieve a similar operation by feeding the second link to the Android tablet, through some "intent"? I know very little about Java and have no idea how to make use of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635269/launch-onenote-using-share-intent-in-android) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799174/how-to-send-url-to-onenote-android-app) [posts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-onedrive-shared-onenote-how-to-open-on/6b26141d-3988-45d4-9c88-5648f17de608). Mainly, I'm looking for a long `adb` command with appropriate flags that may take, likely, the second link as input and have the Android tablet open the page by responding to some intent.

Eventually, with the long `adb` command, I see myself wrapping it in a bash function, and calling it by feeding in the full link that starts with `onenote:https://d...`.

---

**Update1**: thanks to user M. A.'s [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/247336/295871), I can send the `onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/...` link to the Android tablet - However, OneNote APK seems to only comprehend up to the section name in the `onenote:...` link despite the whole thing consists of page-specific pointers.

Here is a demo where I fed in a **full link** pointing to a page, which was sent as an intent to only go to the relevant **section**.
[image]

PS: in OneNote, things are organized as Notebook/Section/Page/Subpage. In the screenshot above, the Notebook is "Paperless", and I have masked out the name for the section and page.

---

**Update2**: for the full page-specific URL to work, we actually need to escape the `&` signs in `&section-id`, `&page-id` and `&end`.

Comment: Related: [Sending intents using ADB with additional action, data, and extra](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/68105/44325)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have OneNote APK installed on your mobile phone, try this:

```
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d " \"onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/....\" "
```

Note, the `&section-id`, `&page-id` and `&end` bits in the `onenote:https://...` URL will draw special attention from the interpreter (see Update 1 in the original question).

[Spikatrix](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/119266/spikatrix) offered a simpler solution in the comment below: to wrap the whole OneNote link first as a string with quotation marks escaped, and then add another pair of quotes to pass the string to the shell.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a special trick to wrap the URL fed through the `-d` flag? Per my updated screenshots, it seems like either the `adb` or the "shell on the Android tablet(?)" was trying to make more sense out of `&section-id`, `&page-id` and `&end`.

Comment: I tried to escape `&` as `\&` in the URL, and it worked!

Comment: Oh, I should have asked this before updating your reply - is there an out-of-the-box way to escape those `&` signs in the URL?

Comment: @llinfeng Try wrapping the entire string in quotes like so: `"one & two"` would be `"\"one & two\""`

Comment: @Spikatrix Perfect! This worked better than escaping `&`  signs! I ended up passing the OneNote link as `" \"onenote:https://...&section-id={xxx}...&end\" "`. (I added two spaces to make the inner string stand out.)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the method documented in this gist: https://gist.github.com/llinfeng/affd7911645d7e8502b20d6f0a612842. In general, I find it helpful that Github "gists" should have better version control, and decide to leave all the code component there in a public gist.

The method described in the gist works in three steps:

1. Create a parser script that deal with the bits that contain `&`, namely, these three: `&section-id`, `&page-id` and `&end`
2. Create a wrapper function in Zsh that will pass the long OneNote string into the parser script, and
3. Create an alias in Zsh that can activate the wrapper function in step 2 with `one` as a shorthand.

With the alias defined there, issuing `one "LongLink2Page"` in Zsh will get the page loaded on the Android tablet. Future improvement would be to update the parser script to read directly from the clipboard.